# Column order manipulation using col-push and col-pull in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a form with three responsive views (mobile, tablet, desktop) using the Bootstrap Grid system. My mobile and tablet view are working correctly but I am having trouble with the desktop view. 
For mobile I have two user input forms that are lined up as so:

```
[12] 
[12]
```

For tablet:

```
[offset:3][6]
[offset:3][6]
```

For desktop I want it too look like:

```
[4][4]  *centered in the middle of the page*
```

I believe I can do this using col-push and col-pull?

Here is my code:

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 "></div>
   <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4"></div> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to offset just the first column, and [reset the offset](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) in the second column, like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0"></div> 
</div>
```